# get thumbnail with google api feed

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml

I have had write this code to parse rss reader with google feed api:

```
var thefeeds=result.feed.entries
var theDiv = document.getElementById("title1");
theDiv.innerHTML +=  thefeeds[0].title;
var theDiv = document.getElementById("lunch_1")
theDiv.innerHTML +=  thefeeds[0].content;
```

in this i have result but when i enter the code to get the mediagroup, there was no displaying of results, is this wrong?

```
thefeeds[0].mediaGroup.contents.thumbnail[0].url;
```